# why won't \n and <br> work in a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to print out content in an object, and some of those properties have 
 tags in them which is why I can't just randomly create new elements in js because I don't know which properties will have 
 tags. But they're not rendering in my browser. I feel like I'm missing a very simple concept here... An example is provided below

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tvzgypd6/3/

Here is just an example of an object that won't display properly when I use ng-repeat in angular

```
$scope.objs = [
    {a : 'test 1 <br> test 1'},
    {a : 'test 2 '},
    {a : 'test 3'},
    {a : "test 4 \n test 4"},
    {a : 'test 5 \n test 5'},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it through CSS:

```
p {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

here a fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/em0r3krw/

Answer (score 0):

In order to show html you should use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and `ng-sanitize`:

```
angular.module('test', ['ngSanitize'])
```

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    <p ng-bind-html="obj.a"></p>
</li>
```

In html `\n` won't actually add a new line. So you should use `white-space: pre;` as pointed out by zwacky:

```
p {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9dca9kj/1/)